# Ordering the results based on the where condition

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, where-clause

Suppose that `table1` has 3 attributes: `first_name`, `last_name`, and `country`. For example with the following tuples:

```
John White Canada
John Smith France
Mary Smith Canada
Ben  Smith Canada
Mary Black USA
```

I am looking for those with first name, "John", or last name "Smith", or country "US":

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE
    first_name='John' or
    last_name='smith' or
    country='US'
```

I want to get the result in the following order:
First those with first name, John, then those with last name smith, and last those with country US

I know that I can write the following 3 different queries and then use their output in the order I want:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE first_name='John'

SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE last_name='smith'

SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE country='US'
```

I am looking for a better way.

Question1: if I use the mentioned 3 queries and find their union the order will change, right? If yes, how can I append the results?

Question2: Is there a better way?

Answer (score 5):

Your ORDER BY should be something like

```
ORDER BY CASE
           WHEN FIRST_NAME = 'John' THEN 1
           WHEN LAST_NAME = 'smith' THEN 2
           ELSE 3
         END
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `CASE` statement in your `ORDER BY` clause, like so:

```
SELECT    -- We NEVER use SELECT *
    first_name,
    last_name,
    country
FROM
    Table1
WHERE
    first_name = 'John' OR
    last_name = 'Smith' OR
    country = 'US'
ORDER BY
   CASE WHEN first_name = 'John' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
   CASE WHEN last_name = 'Smith' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
   CASE WHEN country = 'US' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```